# Replace key:value pair in JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following JSON:

```
var json = [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "key1": "Name1",
        "key2": 2,
        "key3": 1
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "key1": "Name2",
        "key2": 2,
        "key3": 1
    }, 
    {
        "id": "3",
        "key1": "Name3",
        "key2": 2,
        "key3": 1
    }
]
```

And I need to replace one object with another.
For example, I want to replace:

```
{
    "id": "2",
    "key1": "Name2",
    "key2": 2,
    "key3": 1
}
```

with

```
{
    "id": "5",
    "key1": "Name7",
    "key2": 3,
    "key3": 2
}
```

So far I can only filter the array of objects:

```
var id = 2;
var newObj = {"id": "5", "key1": "Name7", "key2": 3, "key3": 2};
var filtered = json.filter(function(el) {
     return el.id === id;
});
console.log(filtered);
```

What's next? How to replace object with `id === 2` with the `newObj`?

Comment: That's not JSON, it's an array of objects that happens to be created via literal syntax. JSON is a string representation of an object/array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use method [Array.prototype.findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex):

```
var id = "2"; // ids are strings in your json object
var newObj = {"id": "5", "key1": "Name7", "key2": 3, "key3": 2};
var idx = json.findIndex(function(el) {
    return el.id === id;
});
if (~idx) { // the same as `idx > -1`
    json[idx] = newObj;
}
```

However `findIndex` is not supported in all browser so check for compatibility in your environment on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex#Browser_compatibility).

You can use cross-browser solution and replace `findIndex` with `reduce`:

```
var idx = json.reduce(function(r, el, i) {
    return !~r && el.id === id ? i : r;
}, -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

the `===` mean "equality without type coercion", so you can converts number to string,

```
var id = 2; //id a number, but json[i].id is string 
var newObj = {"id": "5", "key1": "Name7", "key2": 3, "key3": 2};
var filtered = json.filter(function(el) {
     return el.id === String(id); // or id.toString() and id + ''
});
console.log(filtered);
```